# A pip install doesn't add anything to pipFile or pipFile.lock

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

when I try to install a package to the Django with `pip install` terminal shows the package is installed and I can see the progress but nothing appear inside the Pipfile or Pipfile.lock.

Steps that I followed:

1. `pip install elasticsearch-dsl`
2. package installed on the terminal (saw that multiple times)

> ````
> Requirement already satisfied: six in d:\development\pythonsetting\lib\site-packages (from elasticsearch-dsl) (1.12.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in d:\development\pythonsetting\lib\site-packages (from elasticsearch-dsl) (2.8.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: elasticsearch<7.0.0,>=6.0.0 in d:\development\pythonsetting\lib\site-packages (from elasticsearch-dsl) (6.4.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in d:\development\pythonsetting\lib\site-packages (from elasticsearch<7.0.0,>=6.0.0->elasticsearch-dsl) (1.25.7)```
> ````

3. checked my pipfile:

```
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
black = "*"
pylint = "*"

[packages]
django = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
django-rest-knox = "*"


[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

How can I add this package to my django project?

Comment: Are you sure you have your project env activated, not global ? What does your `pip list` say ?

Comment: it appears on the pip list (yes I am running it on virtual env)

Comment: I can see all the package that i tried to install when i do pip list ```django-elasticsearch-dsl 7.1.0
elasticsearch            6.4.0
elasticsearch-django     6.5
elasticsearch-dsl        6.4.0```

Comment: Did you lock your files with `$ pipenv lock` ?

Comment: I did not run ```pipenv lock``` should I?

Comment: Yea, pipenv is a subsitution to requirements.txt file. Just as you want to save your packages to requirements file, you also have to lock your files in pipenv

Comment: i am having the success message ```Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Success!
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (7458f6)!``` but pipfile still the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved the situation by changing my command from `pip install elasticsearch-dsl` to `pipenv install elasticsearch-dsl`

and it worked

Comment: You mean *from* `pip install` *to* `pipenv install`. Thanks, it worked for me, too.